# jersey webservices 404 error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

i know there are many similar questions with lot of answers.But none of them actually helped me in resolving the issue. Thats why i decided to post a new question.So basically i am using jersey with angular front end .When i execute my url http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/rest/leave/list ,it shows 404 error "The requested resource is not available".following is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.abc.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and webservice:

```java
package com.abc.rest;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.abc.dao.AddLeaveDao;

import com.abc.dao.LeaveDao;

import com.abc.entity.LeaveBalance;
//import com.abc.entity.Love;
import com.abc.entity.LeaveDetails;

@Path("/leave")
public class LeaveWS {

    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public List<LeaveBalance> list() {
        List l= new LeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
        return l;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("create")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String create(LeaveDetails ld) {

        new AddLeaveDao().addDetails(ld);
        System.out.println("Returned  here");
        return "{}";
    }




}
```

and the project structure:

[image]

please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: please, stop using code snippet for things other than JS/HTML and browser-compliant languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your resource your path mapping should be prefixed with "/"

```
@Path("/list")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public List<LeaveBalance> list() {
    List l= new LeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
    return l;
}
```

After the this change if you are using maven , execute mvn clean install to have your resources updated

Comment: are you sure your server is running under  http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs?

Comment: yes i am as the code was working before.I had to refactor the code and rename some of the package and variables.It stopped working since then ...everything seems fine ..Dont understand where i am going wrong

Comment: what did you refactor exactly?

Comment: created new package and moved files there .Renamed WS class,changed  @path from blog to list ,updated web.xml with the new package name and new url pattern..

Comment: if you are using maven try to do mvn clean install

Comment: update the answer with maven suggestion and i will accept the answer

Comment: answer is updated though this is not the original issue

Comment: yes ,but it might help someone facing the same issue.People usually dont read comments as much as they do with answers